# how to pass multiple parameter to controller via actionlink and output in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to asp.net mvc3 and I am having a hard time figuring this out.
I have an actionlink which i want to include a parameter and pass to my Index Method

> ```
> @Html.ActionLink("Click here", "Index", "Customer", new { customerid = item.custId}, new {       @class = "partiallink" })
> ```

How do i receive it from the controller? considering that there is no method parameter in my Index Action method and also how do I output the parameter in the view?

I guess what I'm trying to say is pass it to some controller method and still returns the Index page with the paramters

Comment: Are you trying to pass customerid to Index? But it contains no parameters.

Answer (score 1):

All parameters that you pass to action link become a querystring parameter i.e.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here", "Index", "Customer", new { customerid = 111, someOtherParameter = 222, anotherParameter = 333}
```

transfer to link  /Customer/Index?customerid=111&someOtherParameter=222&anotherParameter=333.
You can get it in controller through `Request.QueryString`property or map it through model binder if signature of Index action is:

```
ActionResult Index(int? customerid, int? someOtherParameter, string anotherParameter)
{
    .....
}
```

Comment: I don't know why the parameters I pass don't become part of the query string. Why is that? Does that mean it doesn't work for the current version of .net?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying, on your Customer controller, you want to be able to pass either no value, or a customerid to your Index action, which returns the Index page?

Assuming you haven't changed the default route, you can alter your controller action to accept a nullable int, and then get your model based on whether the customerid is null:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? customerid)
    {
        YourModelType model;
        if (customerid == null)
        {
            model = /* however you get your model when you don't have an id */
        }
        else
        {
            model = /* however you get your model when you have an id */;
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

You'll also need to update your routing engine to accept the optional customerid parameter:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Customer", // Route name
            "Customer/{action}/{customerid}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", customerid = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar to below example

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here", "Index", "Customer", new { ID= 111,UID =222}, null)
```

and in controller

```
[HttpGet,Route("Index/{ID}/{UID}")]
        public ActionResult EventView(int ID,int UID)
        {
        }
```

Please refer below link as well ,it is useful

[Query string not working while using attribute routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642874/query-string-not-working-while-using-attribute-routing)