# Multiple actions were found that match the request in Web Api using Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Out of curiosity, I was trying to build API with the number of overloads.

Initially, I was getting the below error

-[Multiple actions were found that match the request in Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534167/multiple-actions-were-found-that-match-the-request-in-web-api)

But again, I wanted to give some try in other way opposed to mentioned in the above link.

I went ahead & decorated my API with `[Route]` & here is how my API looks like.

```
namespace CTB_APP.Controllers.API.Delete
{
[RoutePrefix("api/test/")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("name")]
    public string Get(string param)
    {
        return param + 1;
    }

    [Route("age")]
    public int Get(int param)
    {
        return param + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

I was thinking that the above the API could be easily served at the respective endpoints.

```
http://localhost:51370/api/test/name?param=Chetan

http://localhost:51370/api/test/age?param=28
```

But this is returning the below error.

> {
>       "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51370/api/test/age?param=28'.",
>       "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Test' that matches the name 'age'."
>   }

Please note Attribute routing is enabled.

WebAPIConfig.cs

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

How can I fix this??

Thanks.

Comment: include `[HttpGet]` and see if that makes a difference

Comment: @Nkosi, Passing the parameter in query string is not something I would personally prefer its just try that I am doing hence didn't added the configuration, ideally I would structure my endpoints as  `http://localhost:51370/api/test/name?param=Chetan`

Comment: I am going to try and see if I can reproduce this

Comment: Tested what you had and it hits the action as expected.

Comment: Ok figured it out. When I tested it I instinctively removed the additional slash `/` from the route prefix and it worked. You problem therefore is that you have an addition slash in the route prefix

Comment: @Nkosi, as suggested by Tom (in the ans) I need to update the Route decoration & then my endpoints are getting hit

Answer (score 3):

When I tested it I instinctively removed the additional slash `/` from the route prefix and it worked.

Your problem therefore is that you have an addition slash in the route prefix, which i believe is not allowed.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test/")]
```

causes the following error

> *"The route prefix `api/test/` on the controller named `Test` cannot end with a `/` character"*

Remove the slash at the end of the route template

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
```

The following in-memory test was used to verify the expected behavior

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [Test]
    public async Task __WebApi_Should_Match_Route() {
        //Arrange
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        var httpServer = new HttpServer(config);
        var client = new HttpClient(httpServer);

        //Act
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/test/age?param=28");
        var returnJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //Assert
        response.IsSuccessStatusCode.Should().BeTrue();

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(returnJson);
        result.Should().Be(29);
    }
}



[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController {
    [Route("name")]
    public string Get(string param) {
        return param + 1;
    }

    [Route("age")]
    public int Get(int param) {
        return param + 1;
    }
}
```

Also ensure that attribute routing must be enabled before convention-based routes

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: You mean to say in your case you didn't need  to update the `[Route("age/{param}")]`

Comment: No. I only removed the extra slash and everything else worked.

Comment: in my case it didn't

Comment: Strange, can you please upload your src to some cloud(dropbox) & share??

Comment: In fact, the error mesage returned says *"The route prefix `api/test/` on the controller named `Test` cannot end with a `/` character"*

Comment: agreed. Even I got the same & removed the / from the url as you mentioned

Comment: Please share your WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Check the arrange section of the test

Comment: @Kgn-web show your WebApiConfig. maybe you did not configure something correctly. Note attribute routing must be enabled before convention-based routes

Comment: Added WebAPIConfig please check!!

Comment: Most important bit here for me was `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you've not told the route itself to expect a parameter, try registering your attributes for your routes as:

```
[Route("name/{param=param}")]
```

And if that doesn't work try:

```
[HttpGet, Route("name/{param=param}")]
```

Related [Stackoverflow Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642874/query-string-not-working-while-using-attribute-routing)

Comment: Yes. it serves!! But checking the approach mentioned by Nksoi

Comment: Anyways!! Thanks Upvoting your post for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace CTB_APP.Controllers.API.Delete
{
[RoutePrefix("api/test/")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("name/{param}")]
    public string Get(string param)
    {
    return param + 1;
    }

   [Route("age/{param}")]
   public int Get(int param)
   {
      return param + 1;
   }
 }
}
```

End Point 1:  http://localhost:51370/api/test/name/mm
End Point 2:  http://localhost:51370/api/test/age/9

Comment: Tested in my application and its working as expected :)