# Issue with Attribute Routing working with traditional form parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having trouble with using attribute routing in ASP.NET MVC 5. Here is the action im using in my controller:

```
[HttpGet,Route("Home/ChangeID/{MovieInput}")]
public ActionResult ChangeID(int MovieInput)
{
    return View();
}
```

Here is the form I am using to send the parameter to this action:

```html
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("ChangeID", "Home")">
    <label for="movieInput">Change an ID: </label>
    <input type="text" id="MovieInput" name="MovieInput" placeholder="Enter Your ID" />
    <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

The route works perfectly with a URL such as

```
/Home/ChangeID/65
```

however it does not support the form submission parameter typing where its

```
/Home/ChangeID?MovieInput=65`.
```

How can I change the form submission to meet the latter or is there a way to change the route to satisfy a parameter typed this way?
`

Comment: If you change route to `Route("Home/ChangeID")` it will work for the form action. or make the route parameter optional `Route("Home/ChangeID/{MovieInput?}"` (note the `?`) it should have the same effect. The advantage of the second option over the first is that it will allow both `/Home/ChangeID/65` and `/Home/ChangeID?MovieInput=65`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query string not working while using attribute routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642874/query-string-not-working-while-using-attribute-routing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change route template to `Route("Home/ChangeID")`

```
//GET /Home/ChangeID?MovieInput=65`
[HttpGet,Route("Home/ChangeID")]
public ActionResult ChangeID(int MovieInput) {
    return View();
}
```

it will work for the form action or make the route parameter optional `Route("Home/ChangeID/{MovieInput?}")` (note the `?`)

```
//GET /Home/ChangeID/65`
//GET /Home/ChangeID?MovieInput=65`
[HttpGet,Route("Home/ChangeID/{MovieInput?}")]
public ActionResult ChangeID(int MovieInput) {
    return View();
}
```

it should have the same effect.

The advantage of the second option over the first is that it will allow both `/Home/ChangeID/65` and `/Home/ChangeID?MovieInput=65` to match the controller action.