# Why the second parameter value is always null in action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The second parameter value for the action method is always null. In the uri the query string contains values for both status and type. But I can get value only for the status. The type parameter is always null.

I've tried attribute routing as answered in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22962461/8155033

I added         [Route("Vehicles")]        [Route("Vehicles/{status}/{type}")] attribute routes as mentioned in that answer. It matches with 
https://localhost:44355/Vehicles/8481aaed-13f8-4eee-921b-20853ab9ddf0/c07f4dd0-44d2-4c82-b174-76849d010c95%2F

but not with 
https://localhost:44355/Vehicles?status=8481aaed-13f8-4eee-921b-20853ab9ddf0&type=c07f4dd0-44d2-4c82-b174-76849d010c95%2F

VehiclesController

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Guid? status, Guid? type )
   {
            var applicationDbContext = _context.Vehicles.Where(v=> v.VehicleStatusId == status && v.VehicleTypeId == type).Include(v => v.VehicleStatus).Include(v => v.VehicleType);
            return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
   }
```

I want to get values for parameters using this. https://localhost:44355/Vehicles?status=8481aaed-13f8-4eee-921b-20853ab9ddf0&type=c07f4dd0-44d2-4c82-b174-76849d010c95%2F

It gets the value for status, but type is always null.

When I press the submit button I get the above query string.

```
<div>
    <form name="searchbox">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                @{
                    var vStatuses = ViewBag.vStatuses as ICollection<VehicleStatus>;
                    foreach (var vStatus in vStatuses)
                    {
                        <input type="radio" name="status" value=@vStatus.Id />
                        @vStatus.Label
                    }
                }

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @{
                    var vTypes = ViewBag.vTypes as ICollection<VehicleType>;
                    foreach (var vType in vTypes)
                    {

                        <input type="radio" name="type" value=@vType.Id/>
                        @vType.Label
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you remove the %2F at the end?

Comment: The second query string value is not a valid Guid

Comment: @NineBerry Do you have idea why this happened. I have these values as radio buttons when I press the submit button I get this query string

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: What happens if you put a space before `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is that the `type` parameter value is not a valid guid format

you can check it out through link below

[Parse Guid](http://guid.us/Test/GUID)

if you remove `%2F` it will do the trick!

Comment: It works when I remove %2F. I updated the question, It would be great to know why this happens

Comment: i told you so !

Comment: Yes as you and @NineBerry told