# How to enable both "{actionmethod}/id" and "{actionmethod}?id=" routing .net core?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using attribute routing.
Here is my controller:

```cs
[HttpGet("Flights/{Id?}")]
public IActionResult GetFlights(string Id)
{
    var flightroute= _myService.GetFlightsWithRoutes(Id);
    if (flightroute != null)
    {
        return Ok(flightroute);
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

I able to perform

```
https://localhost:44374/air/Flights/AI-109
```

But this shows 404 Not Found response

```
https://localhost:44374/air/Flights?Id=AI-109
```

How can I enable both routing, or can I? I want both routes to call same action method.

Comment: You want both routes to call same action?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query string not working while using attribute routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642874/query-string-not-working-while-using-attribute-routing)