# DotNet - API - Can't access endpoint

Tags: api, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am passing through quite a similar challenge to the one reported on this post - [.Net Core API Endpoint not allowing QueryString parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765748/net-core-api-endpoint-not-allowing-querystring-parameters) - but the accepted answer hasn't worked for me, so I am seeking some guidance.

```
    [HttpGet, Route("api/indicators/getindicatorsvalues/{companyId=companyId}/{pathToFile=pathToFile}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ComputedIndicatorVM), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetIndicatorsValues([FromQuery] Guid companyId, [FromQuery] string pathToFile)
    {
       //code goes here
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IndicatorDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        //some more code goes here
    }
```

**Calling the 1st endpoint:**

**URL:** https://localhost:5001/api/indicators/GetIndicatorsValues?companyId=cTest&pathToFile=ptfTest

**Result:** {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|6c8dcccd-412c0e1f0b9eb222.","errors":{"id":["The value 'GetIndicatorsValues' is not valid."]}}

**Calling the 2nd endpoint works just fine:**

**URL:** https://localhost:5001/api/indicators/DFAF6EAE-AB4B-4563-B37E-57DEF730A1D7

It seems by the response of the first endpoint that it is considering GetIndicatorsValues as a param for the second endpoint?
Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sorted:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IndicatorDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {

        var indicator = await this.indicatorsService.GetByIdAsync(id);
        if (indicator == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(indicator);
    }

    [HttpGet("GetIndicatorsValues")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ComputedIndicatorVM), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetIndicatorsValues([FromQuery] Guid companyId, [FromQuery] string pathToFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (companyId!=default && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToFile))
            {
                List<ComputedIndicatorVM> computedIndicatorsViewModel = new List<ComputedIndicatorVM>();
                List<ComputedIndicatorDto> dtoList = await this.indicatorsService.CalculateIndicators(companyId, pathToFile);
                computedIndicatorsViewModel = this.mapper.Map<List<ComputedIndicatorVM>>(dtoList);
                return Ok(computedIndicatorsViewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems this issue is the https://localhost:5001/api/indicators/GetIndicatorsValues will match both the GetIndicatorsValues and GetByIdAsync. I guess your has a default rule which is like `{controller}/{action}/{id?}`.

I suggest you could try to modify the controller codes to avoid match the same method and then it will work well.

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/indicators/getindicatorsvalues/{companyId=companyId}/{pathToFile=pathToFile}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ComputedIndicatorVM), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIndicatorsValues([FromQuery] Guid companyId, [FromQuery] string pathToFile)
{
   //code goes here
}

[HttpGet("api/indicators/getindicatorsvalues/GetByIdAsync/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IndicatorDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
{
    //some more code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brando for your suggestion, but that hasn't worked.
GetByIdAsync stopped working and GetIndicatorsValues still doesn't work.
I will keep exploring and will post the solution here once I get it.